# Dúvidas com a classe JSObject

Tags: java

"Para passar um valor do applet para o HTML, precisei criar um objeto da classe netscape.javascript.JSObject."

A minha dúvida é essa classe JSObject está funcionando nos navegadores atuais?
Eu fiz um código aqui agora a applet não aparece no navegador. Será por que utilizei a classe JSObject? 
dá a seguinte mensagem de erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que faço?

Comment: Você está criando applet daqueles tipo teclado virtual? Sabe que a compatibilidade com alguns navegadores vai ser descontinuada ne?

Comment: Sim! Sei, Diego você saberia como eu poderia fazer com que a applet fosse traduzida de alguma outra forma?

Comment: Não sei se entendi a dúvida, mas em Java tem o [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29) para manipular Javascript.